# How to compress this type of gltf

Tags: 3d, compression, augmented-reality, gltf

I have a gltf file which has been generated by an iOS app called Record3d. It is a point cloud animated model of a person. Despite animation's small duration (about 5 s), its size is ~ 275MB. Any ideas about how to compress this kind of file without loosing (much) quality? Or any algorithm which can compress and de-compress it efficiently? Draco compression cannot be applied in this case because there are no triangle primitives (see below). Also, there are no textures, so no texture compression.
The gltf file comprises of this data as output by 'gltf-transform' cli: -

```
 METADATA

┌────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ key                │ value                                        │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ version            │ 2.0                                          │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ generator          │ Generated by Record3D (https://record3d.app/ │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ extensionsUsed     │ KHR_materials_unlit                          │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ extensionsRequired │ none                                         │
└────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────┘



 SCENES

┌───┬──────┬──────────┬─────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ # │ name │ rootName │ bboxMin                     │ bboxMax                    │
├───┼──────┼──────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ 0 │      │ rootObj  │ -0.21524, -0.5004, -0.76288 │ 0.41961, 0.20766, -0.17263 │
└───┴──────┴──────────┴─────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘



 MESHES

┌─────┬───────┬────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬─────────┬────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────┬─────────┐
│ #   │ name  │ mode   │ primitives │ glPrimitives │ vertices │ indexed │ components     │ attributes        │ instances │ size    │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 0   │ m_0   │ POINTS │ 1          │ 166,720      │ 166,720  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.54 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ m_1   │ POINTS │ 1          │ 167,622      │ 167,622  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.56 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 2   │ m_2   │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,204      │ 168,204  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.57 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 3   │ m_3   │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,124      │ 168,124  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.57 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 4   │ m_4   │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,228      │ 169,228  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.58 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 5   │ m_5   │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,695      │ 168,695  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.57 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 6   │ m_6   │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,774      │ 168,774  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.58 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 7   │ m_7   │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,500      │ 168,500  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.57 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 8   │ m_8   │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,648      │ 168,648  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.57 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 9   │ m_9   │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,611      │ 168,611  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.57 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 10  │ m_10  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 167,687      │ 167,687  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.56 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 11  │ m_11  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,739      │ 168,739  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.57 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 12  │ m_12  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,426      │ 169,426  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 13  │ m_13  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,657      │ 169,657  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 14  │ m_14  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,486      │ 169,486  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 15  │ m_15  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,541      │ 169,541  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 16  │ m_16  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,586      │ 169,586  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 17  │ m_17  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,227      │ 169,227  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.58 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 18  │ m_18  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,090      │ 170,090  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 19  │ m_19  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,669      │ 170,669  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 20  │ m_20  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,774      │ 168,774  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.58 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 21  │ m_21  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 166,765      │ 166,765  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.54 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 22  │ m_22  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 171,345      │ 171,345  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.61 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 23  │ m_23  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 176,963      │ 176,963  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.7 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 24  │ m_24  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 180,141      │ 180,141  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.75 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 25  │ m_25  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 182,183      │ 182,183  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.78 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 26  │ m_26  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 186,348      │ 186,348  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.84 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 27  │ m_27  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 189,531      │ 189,531  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.89 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 28  │ m_28  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 190,657      │ 190,657  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.91 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 29  │ m_29  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 190,599      │ 190,599  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.91 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 30  │ m_30  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 191,420      │ 191,420  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.92 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 31  │ m_31  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 192,071      │ 192,071  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.93 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 32  │ m_32  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 194,014      │ 194,014  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.96 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 33  │ m_33  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 189,914      │ 189,914  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.9 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 34  │ m_34  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 187,736      │ 187,736  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.86 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 35  │ m_35  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 187,520      │ 187,520  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.86 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 36  │ m_36  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 188,186      │ 188,186  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.87 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 37  │ m_37  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 187,683      │ 187,683  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.86 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 38  │ m_38  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 188,479      │ 188,479  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.88 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 39  │ m_39  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 187,631      │ 187,631  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.86 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 40  │ m_40  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 186,482      │ 186,482  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.85 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 41  │ m_41  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 185,419      │ 185,419  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.83 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 42  │ m_42  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 185,349      │ 185,349  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.83 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 43  │ m_43  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 184,592      │ 184,592  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.82 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 44  │ m_44  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 185,162      │ 185,162  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.83 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 45  │ m_45  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 175,038      │ 175,038  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.67 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 46  │ m_46  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 174,151      │ 174,151  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.66 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 47  │ m_47  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 172,921      │ 172,921  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.64 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 48  │ m_48  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 171,847      │ 171,847  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.62 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 49  │ m_49  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,666      │ 169,666  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 50  │ m_50  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,767      │ 168,767  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.58 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 51  │ m_51  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 167,839      │ 167,839  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.56 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 52  │ m_52  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,379      │ 168,379  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.57 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 53  │ m_53  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,870      │ 169,870  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 54  │ m_54  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,868      │ 168,868  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.58 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 55  │ m_55  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,460      │ 169,460  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 56  │ m_56  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,480      │ 170,480  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 57  │ m_57  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,466      │ 170,466  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 58  │ m_58  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,068      │ 170,068  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 59  │ m_59  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,681      │ 170,681  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 60  │ m_60  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 171,137      │ 171,137  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.61 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 61  │ m_61  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 172,557      │ 172,557  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.63 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 62  │ m_62  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 172,795      │ 172,795  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.64 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 63  │ m_63  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 172,632      │ 172,632  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.63 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 64  │ m_64  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 173,481      │ 173,481  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.65 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 65  │ m_65  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 173,949      │ 173,949  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.65 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 66  │ m_66  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 174,402      │ 174,402  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.66 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 67  │ m_67  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 173,908      │ 173,908  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.65 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 68  │ m_68  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 173,834      │ 173,834  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.65 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 69  │ m_69  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 173,998      │ 173,998  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.65 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 70  │ m_70  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 174,201      │ 174,201  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.66 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 71  │ m_71  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 173,511      │ 173,511  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.65 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 72  │ m_72  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 173,269      │ 173,269  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.64 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 73  │ m_73  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 172,742      │ 172,742  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.64 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 74  │ m_74  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 172,061      │ 172,061  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.63 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 75  │ m_75  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 171,980      │ 171,980  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.62 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 76  │ m_76  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 171,949      │ 171,949  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.62 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 77  │ m_77  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 171,366      │ 171,366  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.61 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 78  │ m_78  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 171,573      │ 171,573  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.62 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 79  │ m_79  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 171,847      │ 171,847  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.62 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 80  │ m_80  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 172,124      │ 172,124  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.63 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 81  │ m_81  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 171,416      │ 171,416  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.62 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 82  │ m_82  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,087      │ 170,087  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 83  │ m_83  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,522      │ 169,522  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 84  │ m_84  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,231      │ 169,231  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.58 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 85  │ m_85  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,834      │ 169,834  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 86  │ m_86  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,173      │ 170,173  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 87  │ m_87  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,987      │ 169,987  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 88  │ m_88  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,763      │ 169,763  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 89  │ m_89  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,165      │ 170,165  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 90  │ m_90  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,982      │ 169,982  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 91  │ m_91  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,796      │ 170,796  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.61 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 92  │ m_92  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,929      │ 170,929  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.61 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 93  │ m_93  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 171,005      │ 171,005  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.61 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 94  │ m_94  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,337      │ 170,337  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 95  │ m_95  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,450      │ 170,450  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 96  │ m_96  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 170,155      │ 170,155  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.6 MB  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 97  │ m_97  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,478      │ 169,478  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.59 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 98  │ m_98  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 168,612      │ 168,612  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.57 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 99  │ m_99  │ POINTS │ 1          │ 169,089      │ 169,089  │         │ Float32, Uint8 │ COLOR_0, POSITION │ 1         │ 2.58 MB │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼───────────────
... (truncated one entry)


 MATERIALS

┌───┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬───────────┬─────────────┐
│ # │ name │ instances │ textures │ alphaMode │ doubleSided │
├───┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│ 0 │      │ 101       │          │ OPAQUE    │             │
└───┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴───────────┴─────────────┘



 TEXTURES
 ────────────────────────────────────────────
No textures found.


 ANIMATIONS

┌───┬──────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ # │ name │ channels │ samplers │ duration │ keyframes │ size      │
├───┼──────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 0 │      │ 101      │ 101      │ 3.333    │ 10,201    │ 119.94 KB │
└───┴──────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

While glTF's `KHR_draco_mesh_compression` extension doesn't currently support point clouds, there are two alternative compression methods available that do. You would need to confirm that whatever viewer you are going to display the glTF file in also supports the extension(s) you choose:

- `KHR_mesh_quantization`: Allows the use of (u)int16 or (u)int8 components for vertex data, and might reduce file size by 30-40% (lossy) in this case. Support for this extension is very common.
- `EXT_meshopt_compression`: Alternative (lossy) compression method, MeshOpt can give fairly comparable compression numbers to Draco *if* it is combined with gzip. Support is a bit less common, as of this writing.

In both cases, [gltfpack](https://github.com/zeux/meshoptimizer#-meshoptimizer----) is probably the easiest way to apply the compression to an existing file.

Finally, if you're serving this model over a network, you always have the option of applying gzip, zstandard, or other lossless compression methods to the entire file. Gzip is a common choice on the web because the browser decodes it automatically, and so the viewer doesn't actually have to "support" anything, it just works.